# Reload page only once via location.reload(false);

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked already but none of provided solutions are working on the site I am working on.

The staging site is: http://thetruthmadesimple.com/client/adaire/

I know refreshing isn't good practice but the situation is that the page looks good in Chrome and Safari but when loaded on FF is doesn't display correctly until F5/refresh.

location.reload(false); does reload but it has the same problem as others have had of looping and continuously reloading the page.

I am a novice to JS and jquery so any suggestions and/or solutions would help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach: Reload page with "#2" attached to URL, then check if #2 is attached and do not reload again:

```
if(window.location.hash !== "#2") {
    window.location.href += "#2";
    window.location.reload(false);
}
```

But hey, get your FF rendering in place ;)

Comment: Thanks, when anchor #2 is set in the url it triggers the loop when the page is refreshed. The strange part is is that the FF rendering is in place...when the page is refreshed. I'm not sure what is causing it to be blocked on initial load. I was hoping the force refresh would be a simple solution but I can't figure either out!

Comment: Then another dirty hack could be to set a cookie when the page is reloaded the first time, have the cookie be valid for ~5-10 seconds. Before reloading, check if cookie is set and don't reload if it is. But would rather suggest you open a new question with your actual FF problem though.